Comment or uncomment a single line in Emacs
I'd like to have an emacs-lisp function that comments or uncomments the line the cursor is on.
At the very least, it needs to work in latex-mode and emacs-lisp-mode, as well as in org-mode inside latex and emacs-lisp source code blocks. Of course, it would be nice if the function worked generally, but as a stopgap, just the above situations would be helpful.
There's a built in function, comment-line, whose documentation suggests that it would perform this function, but it's too buggy to be useful.
I've found about a dozen attempts in forum posts and blogs, but none of them works correctly.
I wrote my own comment function that seems to work generally to comment lines. However, it doesn't uncomment. I'd rather not have to take the time to write the uncomment functionality if someone out there has already done it.
To elaborate on what I mean by "too buggy to be useful", if in an org mode latex source block with
  \commandA
  \commandB
  \commandC

I position my cursor on \commandB and execute comment-line, the following results:
  \commandA
  % \commandB
  % \
  commandC

There are numerous other anomalies, and this kind of strange behavior seems to occur more than half the time, so I don't consider comment-line a useful command.

For clarity: Is the problem specific to indented org-mode code blocks?

(And if so, I suggest you also check for an existing org-mode issue, and raise a new one if one does not already exist.)

Does https://github.com/remyferre/comment-dwim-2 do what you want?

@mmmmmm comment-dwim-2 has problems similar to comment-line. It seems likely the Emacs function comment-region, is where the problem is. All the other functions are calling comment-region. The comment-line function I wrote doesn't do so; it just directly writes the appropriate comment characters to the current line.

@phils I'm not sure I know what you mean by "indented org mode code blocks". I  have org-src-preserve-indentation set to nil, which, ironically, seems necessary to get Python blocks to preserve their necessary indentation. I also have org-edit-src-content-indentation set to 2, just as a personal preference.

I have found buggy behavior of various kinds related to indentation for every choice of settings of org-src-preserve-indentation and org-edit-src-content-indentation. All choices seem to be a compromise of which bugs to live with. For that matter, I'm not aware of any feature of Emacs that is free of major, highly intrusive bugs.

I couldn't replicate your comment-line problem when the example latex was left-aligned -- but org-mode seems to want to auto-indent code blocks slightly, and once it had done that I could reproduce your issue.  So I was wondering whether (a) it was only an issue in org-mode code blocks, and (b) furthermore whether it was only an issue if the block was indented.

(I'm trying to narrow down your question.  If your problem is less "commenting doesn't work" and more "commenting doesn't work in this specific scenario", you're liable to get better help.)

(defun comment-or-uncomment (n)
    (interactive "*p")
    (if (or (region-active-p)
            (save-excursion
              (beginning-of-line)
              (looking-at "\\s-*$")))
        (call-interactively 'comment-dwim)
      (comment-or-uncomment-region
       (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position n))))


As phils notes in the comments, the problem is related to indenting. I've found the following kludge seems to work:
(defun comment-line-kludge (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((org-src-preserve-indentation t))
    (comment-line n)))

